# How To add an existing content database to a new web app Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am looking for a way to attache  a content database to a new web application while this database is used by another site, is there a way that i can assign a different GUID but with the same content ?

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious question : Why on earth would you want to have two web sites use the same DB? You should look into *extending* your existing web app, that will make it accessible through a 2nd URL (and even a 2nd authentication mechanism if you need it)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment.
This is just not possible. A content database cannot be mounted twice in a SharePoint farm.

But, there is one solution: Create a SQL backup, restore it as a different database, and mount that database. Thus, create a clone of the content database and mount the clone.

Comment: Thanks for the lovely answer i wanted to check if create a new web app i can access my site as it is down,its giving me an error ,: **error An unexpected error has occurred. Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation ID: bdfaa2a9-5658-477a-8b21-19e728a36261** can you please advice what to do?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing exactly. Did you mount the copied content db to the new web app? What is in the ULS Log for that Correlation ID?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Attach the same content Database to the two different web application, it will throw the error complaining about the GUID.

Even if you clone(backup and restore) the existing the content database then try to mount 2nd copy of the new web application, it will throw the error again and this time will complain about the Site GUID.

Now only workable soultions is,

- Create New web application with new Content Database.
- Take the backup of each site collection using Backup-spsite or from central admin.
- Now restore the site collection to new web app using Restore-spsite.

To understand about the content database and site arch please check this blog.

http://anexinetsp.blogspot.com/2013/10/issues-with-cloning-existing-content.html